# How to call a function containing a callback function from html code?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html file which contain an 'onclick' event that calls a javascript function that also contains a call back function.  I am having problems with the syntax i think, as I cannot not get the call back function to execute. Please can someone advise?
I am getting an 'illegal invocation'  at 'open(x)'.

html:

```
 <div id="div_friend"><img id="friend" class= "image_icon" src="images/friends_icon.png"  onclick="friendReq('sections_panel', 'open');"></div>
```

.js

```
 function friendReq(x,callback){
var section_p = document.getElementById(x);
var option_p = document.getElementById('options_div');
var maxH = '300px';
var max_op = '200px';


//IF 'options_div' IS OPEN, CLOSE IT FIRST.
if(option_p.style.height == max_op){
    option_p.style.height = '0px';
    option_p.style.transition = 'height 0.8s';  <---code works up to here.

    callback(x); // callback function to execute when above code has finnished.DOES NOT EXECUTE.
}else{ // This section works fine.
    if(section_p.style.height == maxH){
        section_p.style.height = '0px';
        section_p.style.transition = 'height 0.8s';
    }else{
        section_p.style.height = maxH;
        section_p.style.transition = 'height 0.8s';
    }
} 
}

function open(id){
var section_p = document.getElementById(id);
var maxH = '300px';

section_p.style.height=maxH;
section_p.style.transition = 'height 0.7s';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, You have a typo:

```
 <div id="div_friend"><img id="friend" class= "image_icon" src="images/friends_icon.png"  onclick="friendReq('sections_panel', 'open'"></div>
```

should be:

```
 <div id="div_friend"><img id="friend" class= "image_icon" src="images/friends_icon.png"  onclick="friendReq('sections_panel', 'open');"></div>
```

And second, You are passing a string to your `friendReq` function, you will never be able to execute a string as a function. You can change your parameter name to something else because in your `friendReq` function, the open parameter is the string you've get from calling it. try removing that parameter as it is not needed to be passes as callback, should be:

```
function friendReq(x){
```

After this, i believe your code should properly call the `open` function

## EDIT to make thinks a little bit clearer.

So, from your html, you are calling `friendReq('sections_panel', 'open');`, where 'open' is not actually a function, nor a reference to your open function, but a simple string. Now, looking at your code design, you would not need to pass your open function as a callback parameter, as they are both in the same scope and see each other. So you could simply do:

```
function friendReq(x){
var section_p = document.getElementById(x);
var option_p = document.getElementById('options_div');
var maxH = '300px';
var max_op = '200px';


//IF 'options_div' IS OPEN, CLOSE IT FIRST.
if(option_p.style.height == max_op){
    option_p.style.height = '0px';
    option_p.style.transition = 'height 0.8s';  <---code works up to here.

    open(x); // callback function to execute when above code has finnished.DOES NOT EXECUTE.
}else{ // This section works fine.
 //rest of your code  
}

}

function open(id){
var section_p = document.getElementById(id);
var maxH = '300px';

section_p.style.height=maxH;
section_p.style.transition = 'height 0.7s';

}
```

Comment: I have corrected my typo error, but now i am getting 'open is not a function' error.

Comment: Check the rest of my edit, just commented why you cannot call the open function.

Comment: I'm sorry, i am trying hard to understand what you have written with regards to not adding the parameter. i don't understand how function friendReq(x){...} can call a callback function without a callback function added as a parameter.

Comment: You dont need to pass a function as a callback, as long as the function you are calling has visibility of the "callback function", I see you are defining your open function bellow the friendReq function, the are both on the same scope so they can see each other. By defining a parameter in your function friendReq called "open", inside the scope of friendReq, open will be that parameter. And from the html, you are passing a string as that parameter, thus, you are setting the variable open as a string inside the scope of your friendReq function.

Comment: so the html code stays the same: onclick="friendReq('sections_panel', 'open');"?

Comment: Just remove the second parameter as it is not needed anymore.

Comment: OK, ive done all you have suggested.  The problem is open(x) is now executed asynchronously. I need open(x) to execute only have the code above it has finished, which is the point in a callback function right?

Comment: the code above is a css transition, there is no way i know off to execute something after a css transition has finished.

Comment: o i see..man. thats problematic. But many thanks for taking the time to help

Comment: just out of curiosity, what would be the html syntax for passing a callback function as a parameter in a javascript function. I suspected i was passing 'open' as a string instead of a function in :  onclick="friendReq('sections_panel', 'open');"???

Comment: I believe that if you do onclick="friendReq('sections_panel', open); (remove quotes) it should work, but i'm not sure, you should give it a test :)

Comment: If you think that your question is answered please accept the answer so this question gets closed.